# Изменить поведение метода класса являющегося свойством друго класса

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы

Есть вот такая схема. Класс `Car` при инициализации в свойства записывает объекты классов `Wheels` и `Motor`.

```
сlass Car:

    def __init__(self):
        self.wheels = Wheels()
        self.motor = Motor()

    def add_element(self, method):
        result = method()
        #save_result
        return result

class Wheels:
    def add(self, value):
        #add element
        pass


class Motor:
    def add(self, value):
        # add element
        pass
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при вызове метода  `add` у `wheels` и `motor` вызывался метод `add_element` у класса `Car`. Пример:

```
my_car = Car()
# должен вызваться метод класса Motor, а результат передаться в my_car.add_element
my_car.motor.add("my_motor") 
# должен вызваться метод класса Wheels, а результат передаться в my_car.add_element
my_car.wheels.add("my_wheels")
```

Я совсем запутался, в голову пришел вот такой вариант:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self):
        self.wheels = Wheels()
        self.wheels.add = self.add_element(self.wheels.add)
        self.motor = Motor()
        self.motor.add = self.add_element(self.motor.add)

    def add_element(self, method):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = method(*args, **kwargs)
            # save_result
            return result
        return wrapper
```

Но если таких свойств у класса Car будет много, то получится очень много лишнего кода. Может у кого-нибудь есть хороший вариант решения данной задачи.
Идея в том, чтобы объект класса Car узнавал об изменении мотора или колес. Я начинающий программист, так что скорее всего задача выглядит чуть-чуть безумной.

Comment: Сразу вопрос - а зачем ему узнавать об их изменении? Чтобы что? Обычно такое не требуется. Просто когда автомобилю что-то нужно будет от колеса или от мотора, то он к ним обратится, а они уже сами своё текущее состояние знают. Зачем автомобилю где-то держать состояние колёс или мотора вне их самих? Ну то есть сделать такое можно, но зачем?

Comment: Так то самое простое наверное сделать так, чтобы конструкторы колеса и мотора могли принимать на вход ссылку на метод, который они должны дёрнуть в определённый момент (при обновлении, как в вашем случае). Пусть автомобиль при инициализации этих классов передаст им такой метод и пусть они его дёргают в нужный момент.

Comment: @CrazyElf В общем класс Car сохраняет некоторые данные в redis. При изменении части "машины" это нужно отразить в базе. Я думал вынести всю логику работы с redis в какой-нибудь класс BaseCarElement и от него наследоваться, но проблема в том, что в таком случае нужно будет переписать все методы add у классов Wheels и Motor (а в моем случае таких классов как Wheels и Motor гораздо больше).

Comment: @CrazyElf Тут приведен упрощенный пример. В проекте такие классы, как Wheels и Motor хранят данные в своих свойствах, а я пытаюсь сохранять их в redis  и так как обращение всегда идет через класс Car ( `my_car.motor.add()` ), решил в классе Car отлавливать изменения и сохранять их в базу.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за совет